# Scraping Table From Sports Page - AdBlock Interfering

Tags: r, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the 6th (or "Advanced") table from http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html.

Using htmltab, or XML I have been able to scrape tables 1 through 3 using the the interger reference (ie 1 for first table, 2 for second etc) or the XPath. I can't scrape tables 4, 5, or 6 using the same methods, though.

```
library(htmltab)
url <- "http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html"
duketable1 <- htmltab(doc = url, which = 1) #Using number
duketable1 <- htmltab(doc = url, which = "//*[@id='all_roster']") #Using XPath
```

Cannot scrape table 6 (or 4 and 5) using the same framework.

```
duketable6 <- htmltab(doc = url, which = 6)
duketable6 <- htmltab(doc = url, which = "//*[@id='all_advanced']")
```

Same with XML (only reads first three tables)

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html"
tables <- readHTMLTable(url)
names(tables)
```

My best guess is `<div class="adblock">` is affecting something but I have no idea how to get around it. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source-code (in chrome i.e. [view-source:http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html](http://view-source:http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html))
You see that the latter tables are commented via `<!--`

Just replace this comment and you can read them. Using `rvest`

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)

doc <- GET("http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/2010.html")
content(doc, "text") %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "<!--\n", "", ., fixed = TRUE) %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_nodes(".table_outer_container table") %>% 
  html_table
```

appending `%>% str(max.level = 1)` results in

```
List of 6
 $ :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  27 variables:
```